# I am having problems with uploading in php. I do not know where the error is, can you help me?

Tags: php, html

I'm following a youtube tutorial on how to create a social network. The code is exactly the same, but when you click on the image to upload something, it does not open. It's like there's nothing to click on. I want to click and open the files to select something and send it to the post. Could anyone help me?
P.S:
Some things are in pt-br, however the code is in english
This is the code part:

```
$n = rand(0, 1000000);
        $img = $n.$_FILES["file"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$img);

        $texto = $_POST['texto'];
        $hoje = date("d-m-y");

        if ($texto == "") {
            echo "<h3>Deve escrever alguma coisa antes de publicar!</h3>";
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO pubs (user,texto,imagem,data) VALUES ('$login_cookie','$texto','$img','$hoje')";
            $data = mysql_query($query) or die();
            if ($data) {
                header("Location: ./");
            }else{
                echo "Alguma coisa não correu muito bem... Tenta outra vez mais tarde";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO1v8.jpg)

link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsXs5-S1e3k
min: 7:28

Comment: *Problem with PHP* is an absolutely useless title. It's clear you have a problem, or you wouldn't be posting here, and it's clear it's with PHP because you added a PHP tag. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will mean something when a future reader sees it in a list of search results. Please [edit] to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I put this title simply because I do not know why. And I explained my problem before putting the code. You're welcome

Comment: @EVELLYNSILVA a good title will attract good reads, and facilitate the search of people who may have a similar problem later. They may even reward you by upvoting your question.

Comment: i get it @YvesLeBorg

Answer (score -1):

I am confused what are exactly trying to say as far as i understand you want to problem with html side because you'r popup dosn't open right  please 
if you want to upload single doc then:-

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

For Multiple :-

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple="multiple" />
```

if you only want your user to upload some images, you can filter on the “image/*” mime-type :

And the PHP script:

```
if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], "datas/" . $_FILES['upload_file']['name'])){
        echo $_FILES['upload_file']['name']. " OK";
    } else {
        echo $_FILES['upload_file']['name']. " KO";
    }
    exit;
} else {
    echo "No files uploaded ...";
}
```

I hope this little example will help you to use HTML5 Apis to upload files.
If Any concern please let me know.